# Correct syntax for querying associated models in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, join, model, scope

I have two models: `LittleClass` and `LittleClassSession`. The `LittleClassSession` `belongs_to` `LittleClass` like so:

```
class LittleClassSession < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :little_class
...
```

I'm attempting to create a named scope inside the `LittleClassSession` model that selects only rows `where` some column of `LittleClass` is some value. Like so:

```
  scope :class_type_only, -> (class_type_id) {
    joins(:little_class)
    .where('little_class_type_id = ?', class_type_id)
  }
```

In the above example, `little_class_type_id` is a columns on `LittleClass`. No error is being thrown, but the results are incorrect. Have I done my join correctly? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
scope :class_type_only, -> (class_type_id) {
  joins(:little_class)
  .where(:little_class => {:little_class_type_id => class_type_id})
}
```